# How do I setup Selenium 2 Server so intern can run functional tests locally, on one browser?

Tags: intern

I want to try running an Intern functional test (i.e. using webdriver) on a single browser, on the local machine.   [The doc](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Tests#as-a-test-runner-for-multi-platform-testing) says that I need a "Selenium 2 Server".

How do I setup the server exactly though?  Do I need to download and install it separately from Intern?   (If so, how?)   And do I need to start it as a separate process, before calling "node runner.js"?   (If so, how?)

Answer (score 11):

intern provides an easy way for you to have everything below the optional machine boundary in this diagram

[image: selenium components]

if you want to run a functional test with intern you don't *need* to have a local selenium server.  [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/) is one option that offers a cloud-based solution which is much less effort than setting up a local selenium server.  there is a video capture of each test and you can also see the tests running live and interact with them if you need to.  also, there are free accounts so you can ease your way into it without being committed.  this is definitely the easiest way to start trying functional testing with intern.

if you really need to have a local server then yes you need to download it and install it separately from intern.  all the pieces above the dotted optional machine boundary line are what *you* need to provide.  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers seems to outline what you would need to do to get the selenium server setup but to be honest i haven't done it myself - i just use saucelabs because it's so simple and does everything i need it to do.

EDIT: I finally got around to setting up selenium locally. it was surprisingly easy - https://gist.github.com/neonstalwart/6630466

Comment: One note though, I have found it quite easy to use SauceLabs, the only challenge though is that you do have to have a way to reach the machine you are running the tests on, which can be challenging in some corporate environments.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers.

Saucelabs looks interesting, and has free usage for open source, although it seems awkward for development of tests in that IIUC the HTML page(s) you are driving need to be a public URL.

Comment: you can use a tunnel so that your pages don't need to be public https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect.  intern makes that part seamless for you, it sets up the tunnel when you start your tests.

Comment: I hadn't realised that!  I just assumed I had to open a port on my firewall.

Answer (score 1):

via the package installer:

download the jarfile for selenium server standalone at SeleniumHQ.org, run with:

```
java -jar path/to/jarfile
```

OR via Brew

```
brew install selenium-server-standalone
selenium-server
```

OR similar via macports

...BTW, you might also want to install the chromedriver:

```
brew install chromedriver
selenium-server -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) came out this has become much easier.
Protractor has a helper bin to help you do this:

```
npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

And now you have a server running.

Comment: This is great, but is this only for Angular?