# Dojo baseUrl error running Intern.io functional tests locally

Tags: dojo, intern

I'm trying to get Intern.io to perform functional tests against a local Selenium standalone server (as asked here: [How do I setup Selenium 2 Server so intern can run functional tests locally, on one browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414829/how-do-i-setup-selenium-2-server-so-intern-can-run-functional-tests-locally-on)) and an answer with some instructions was provided here: https://gist.github.com/neonstalwart/6630466

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
/home/dave/ScratchPad/InternTutorial/intern-tutorial/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:74
            baseUrl = (config.baseUrl || baseUrl).replace(/\/*$/, '/');
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined
```

This was actually the same error I was getting before I followed the instructions. I'm guessing that I have my "loader" attribute configured incorrectly in my "intern.js" file. It's currently set to the following:

```
loader: {
        // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
        //packages: [ { name: 'myPackage', location: '.' } ]
      packages: [ { name: 'app', location: 'app' } ],
      map: { 'app': { dojo: './node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo' } }
    },
```

I'm following the Intern tutorial here: https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial and just want to be able to run the functional tests locally and not against SauceLabs.

Has anyone had any experience of this error and have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: With the possible exception of the environments key, the configuration file isn’t any different when testing against a local Selenium instance versus testing against Sauce Labs. Please post your entire configuration.

Comment: Do you just want the intern.js file or do you want everything (including package.json and Gruntfile.js)? The only part of the configuration that I've changed from these instructions (https://gist.github.com/neonstalwart/6630466) is the loader config (which was why I only posted that part).

Comment: What are you passing as your `config` option on the command-line?

Comment: I'm executing the following: "node node_modules/intern/runner.js config=tests/functional/index" .... (so "tests/functional/index" to answer you question directly).

Comment: The config argument you need to pass is the module ID of your intern.js (aka config file). Not some random test file.

Comment: Excellent, thanks that's worked... apologies for getting that wrong, somewhere along the line I must have merged my "config" and "suites" arguments... I really appreciate you taking the time to help me get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config` argument you need to pass is the module ID of your intern.js (aka config file).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the command you are looking to execute is

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern.js
```

This is if you followed instructions from the tutorial here: https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial/blob/a6b3daf872d11c6ec7edcf4b493de68b47dfe0b6/README.md

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? It's being picked up by the low quality filter.

Comment: Or `intern-client config=tests/intern.js` if intern was installed globally.

Comment: You'll also want to have the selenium webserver running. See http://theintern.github.io/intern/#local-selenium